# Probability that this truncated variable is equal to the original

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to find this probability
$$Pr\{U = X\}$$ where
$$U = X \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,a_n]}(X)$$

$X$ takes on value $2^k$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^kk(k+1)}$ for all $k \geq 1$, and $X = 0$ with probability $1 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^kk(k+1)}$.

And finally $a_n = \frac{n}{log_2(n)}$ although it's not strictly related to my problem.

My reasoning is that:

$$Pr\{U = X\} = \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,a_n]}(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{a_n} 2^k\frac{1}{2^kk(k+1)} = \frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$$

But I would like to confirm if this line of thought is correct?

Comment: "probability $\frac{1}{2^kk(k-1)}$" ...when $k=1$? Hmmm...

Comment: ops fixed the expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that you look for $P(U = X)$ with $U = 1_{(-\infty, c]}(X) X$, with $c>0$.

Then 
\begin{align}
P(U = X) &= P(1_{(-\infty, c]}(X) X = X)\\
&= P(X=0 \text{ or } 1_{(-\infty, c]}(X) = 1)\\
&= P(1_{(-\infty, c]}(X) = 1)\\
&= P(X \le c)\\
\end{align}

Now if $X$ takes the values $x_n$ with probability $p_n$ then
it is
$$
= \sum_{n: x_n \le c } p_n
$$
so the factor $\frac 1{2^k}$ in your writing does not cancel.

Comment: I'm so sorry but if I can just clarify, in my index notation you're saying $\sum_{k: 2^k \le c } \frac{1}{2^k k(k+1)}$, correct?

Comment: correct.${}{}{}$